# CoreBluetooth write data with byte array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, byte

i'm currently trying to send out data with 7bytes from Central to Peripheral using corebluetooth, i have my code as follow:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

connectingPeripheral = peripheral
for characteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!{ 

if characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "2AF2"{
    connectingCharacteristicWrite = characteristic
}

@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) {
    let value: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07]
    let data = NSData(bytes: value, length: 7)
    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic)
    connectingPeripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: connectingCharacteristicWrite, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
}
```

but i can only send one byte with this. I have try following lines of code:

```
let value: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07]
let data = NSData(bytes: value, length: 7)
connectingPeripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: connectingCharacteristicWrite, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

but still cannot send out data. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you add all the code related to connecting to the peripheral and discovering its services and characteristics?

Comment: Also, where do you get connectingCharacteristicWrite from?

Comment: Hi, yup i have edited my question

Comment: What are the attributes of your characteristic? Does it have the write permission?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified solution for Swift 5

```
let value: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07]
connectingPeripheral.writeValue(Data(value), for: connectingCharacteristicWrite, type: .withResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let value: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07]
let data = NSData(bytes: value, length: 7)
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried with your code, but still same, i can't receive any value from the other side

Comment: Can you update your question to outline your actual problem more effectively? In its current form, you are just asking how to define an array of UInt8s.

Comment: Hi, yup i have updated my question. But with array i still cannot send data with 7 Bytes

Comment: Mark's answer should work.  Have you tried replacing your write call with the WithoutResponse option?

I have had issues with writing to lesser BLE devices with the WithResponse option.

Comment: Hi, you just change the option from WithResponse to WithoutResponse then it works?