# I want to send an array of bytes [UInt8] through a CoreBluetooth characteristic

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I want to send an array of bytes `[UInt8]` through a CoreBluetooth characteristic. I have been able to send a string by doing:

```
let data: String = "1"
let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
connectedPeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: fileBlockCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

But don't know how to do this for a `[UInt8]`. Here is what I have tried so far based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480804/corebluetooth-write-data-with-byte-array) but the callback doesn't print on the receiving device:

```
let array: [UInt8] = Array(fileData!.dropFirst(startIndex).prefix(byteCount))
connectedPeripheral.writeValue(Data(array), for: fileBlockCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

and

```
let array: [UInt8] = Array(fileData!.dropFirst(startIndex).prefix(byteCount))
let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count)
                                
connectedPeripheral.writeValue(Data(data), for: fileBlockCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

and

```
let array: [UInt8] = Array(fileData!.dropFirst(startIndex).prefix(byteCount))
let data = Data(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: array), count: array.count, deallocator: .none)
print("data: \(data)")
```

I followed the comment below and tried the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904588/how-can-i-convert-my-uint8-array-to-data-swift) for converting UInt8 array to bytes, but that didn't seem to be my problem. I tried both solution above in any case, but the data is still not getting passed to the bluetooth device, when the string does. It's not erroring (or I don't know how to trap the error in CoreBluetooth) and I do ask for `withResponse`. I have `withoutResponse` and I get error messages (does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write), so I'm pretty sure the call itself is correct...again the string version works too.

On the device I have a callback which works for the string but not the Data(array):

```
void onFileBlockWritten(BLECentral& central, BLECharacteristic& characteristic) {  
  Serial.println("writing file block...");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Something else is happening. I sent in a fixed array of 2 UInt8 values and it worked. The `byteCount` had been set to 128 so I experimented with a few values. At 20 it worked, at 21 it did not.

I increased the value which could be accepted from the other side to 150 and tried 21 again, and it still didn't work.

```
let array: [UInt8] = Array(fileData!.dropFirst(startIndex).prefix(20))
let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count)
connectedPeripheral.writeValue(Data(data), for: fileBlockCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert my UInt8 array to Data? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904588/how-can-i-convert-my-uint8-array-to-data-swift)

Comment: One of the attempts covered converting it to data by passing the array in the Data constructor, which didn't work. I tried the 2nd option and included it in the post, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @jnpdx I moved it out of SwiftUI. I was coding in SwiftUI so I just tagged it, but I added CoreBluetooth and removed SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the *only* thing you can write to a Characteristic is "an array of bytes." You might call it a Sequence of UInt8, or a Data, or `[UInt8]`. These are all Swift concepts, but on the wire, it's always just an array of bytes. That's exactly what you're doing with the String. You convert it to a Data (which is an array of bytes), and send it.

Your problem is the MTU (maximum transfer unit). This device probably doesn't have advanced BLE features, and so is limited to 20 bytes. This size is very common with older or low-cost devices (even some new and pricey devices). BLE was designed for very short messages.

It's possible your device does support the required extensions which allow much larger payloads (~250 bytes). Look for [Data Length Extension](https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-part-3-data-length-extension-dle-2/). The device will need to support at least Bluetooth 4.2, though not all Bluetooth 4.2 devices support DLE. In particular, the iPhone 6s does not.

You can get the maximum length for a characteristic by calling `maximumWriteValueLength(for:)`.

You'll likely need to chunk your data into multiple writes.

Comment: I got `maxWriteLength: 512` from calling `print("maxWriteLength: \(peripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse))")`

Comment: To your point, its probably on the peripheral side. I'm using nrf, arduino, and [this library which seems to set MTU to 23](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Asandeepmistry%2Farduino-BLEPeripheral%20mtu&type=code)